# How to minimize the .apk size in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am making a simple video call app by using Jitsi Android SDK after completion when i build my signed APK its size is too big i.e, 101 MB when i check that apk it shows the type **.nox apk**.

Another problem is when i tried to install that 101MB apk into Mobile it says **App Not Installed**
for this i checked mobile settings **Unknown Sources** after that it stick to the same message (App not installed).

this is my App's **build.gradle(app)** file

[image: This is My app's Dependencies]

**Here is my Proguard Rule also and target SDK**

[image]

and this is the extention of APk file

[image]

here is my analyze apk result

[image]
How to build reduced Apk which run easily...Please Help me into this i don't know where i am going wrong ??

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also i don't have images in my Res Folder i always use Vector asset as a image in my Apps i use only one PNG file which is 7 KB of size

Comment: What are the things inside every folder in `lib`? (I think they all have the same name.) Do you really need some `.so` file for native application?

Comment: @GenoChen in every folder there are so many .so files i only want to reduce the size of apk it is for testing purpose

Comment: For the first question, I mean editing the question for adding information of the last image.

Comment: Look into using App Bundles instead of APK's. App Bundles result in reduced apk sizes when installed, although by how much in your particular case I'm not sure. https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

Comment: @TechRando i tried app bundle apk size is reduced to 39 MB but when i transfer apk into mobile and try to install it it says app not installed ...but why ??

Comment: @GenoChen i didn't get your point

Comment: @AnuragTiwari I mean, what thing is inside `lib/x86_64`?

Comment: @Geno Chen alot of files with extension .so

Comment: @AnuragTiwari What file? Update your question.

Comment: @GenoChen i updated the question with images of each folder last 4 images are the files for which you are asking about. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for your app to be that big is because of all the native libraries which you have in your project. I guess they are included by `Jitsi Android SDK`.
I guess you are not creating App Bundle but building directly an apk via Android Studio, that's why all versions of native libraries are included in the same apk.
By using App Bundle format to build your app you should lower a lot your app's size, because it will create apk files only for the specific configurations, so every architecture will have it's own apk with included native libraries for only that architecture.

Once you have the `App Bundle` file you can create your apk's in order to install to a device using [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool). With a command like this:

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/PathToMyABB/app-bundle.aab --output=/PathToMyAPKS/my-apks.apks
```

Comment: ok i got your point but when i build a bundle it will create a file **app-debug.aab** size of 121MB and i don't know what will be the next step to reduce the size. whether it is remain unchanged or can be reduced

Comment: The next step will be to create the actual apk files from this app bundle and to install them to your device using: `bundletool` -> https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

Comment: i have no idea how to use bundletool i am beginner in android studio

Comment: It's a command line tool, you won't be using it from Android Studio. Check the link which I've posted in the comment and in the main answer.

Comment: I tried this method after creating almost 15 apks and I checked every APK all of them giving same message **parsing problem occurred** @hardartcore

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve apk as bundle and convert your images to webp format you are going to save %50 memory area.

Comment: i dont have any images in my app

Answer (score 0):

1. First of All You Need to Tinify the Resource images [Tinyfy](https://tinypng.com), I suggest you to use this link to tinify your image assets.
2. The Second thing after the above Step, Convert all Image Assets to **Webp Format**, in order to convert to **webp** you need to right click on image asset and then at the Bottom of option there will be optionj convert to webp.
3. Remove Unnecessary classes and libraries to Reduce the Size.
4. Apply Proguard Rules to Reduce Size
5. In Order to remove **delete x86_64** you just need to do is, just add this under Android Tag in app level gradle File

   splits {
   abi {
   enable true
   reset()
   include 'armeabi-v7a'
   universalApk false
   }
   }
   [image: Split APk]

Comment: how to apply point number 3 and by the way i am using only one image throughout the app which is only 7KB

Comment: In Order to achieve this You Just need to open your Gradle File and Check out which Libraries you no longer needed, As Your Build Analyzer Image is Showing which Library Is Consuming More Space or which is Less. Just Remove Unnecessary Libraries

Comment: The Analyzer Showing two of Your Libraries Consuming 8.2 Mbs and I think Both Of them doing same Functionality.

Comment: I order to Achive this You Just Need a Complete analysis of Libraries which are no longer needed.

Comment: One More thing You can do to reduce size is Apply Proguard Rules.

Comment: i have added the proguard rule please check above

Comment: If all of the Above Option not work then there is also an option that playstore provide is upload app in two chunks.

Comment: i am blank how to remove these folders or library inside gradle file all library files are useable

Comment: Just Open Build.gradle File, In there the Above Libraries occupying 8.2 mb or others, and check out which library is no longer needed, As I am pretty sure If You added the library in Gradle then you definitely know the use of that libraries

Comment: i am only using firebase bom,analytics,firebasefirestore and jitsi library which is required

Comment: is there any way to delete x86_64 etc these folders..?

Comment: Yes It is Possible, since It is libtesseract library You can delete the Library from Gradle But I think this library you are using in Projectx=

Comment: can we talk over phone or zoom if you don't mind

Comment: Add this in App Level Gradle Under Android Tag
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }

Comment: @Anurag Tiwari It is too Late but this might help new comers in order to reduce size, I have just updated the answer, just add splits { abi { enable true reset() include 'armeabi-v7a' universalApk false } } under android in app level build.gradle